# Is it possible to impersonate a user without logging him on?

Tags: security, winapi, visual-c++, impersonation

Is it possible to impersonate a user without supplying user name/password? Basically, I'd like to get the `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA` for a user (not the current one) using the `ShGetFolderPath()` function. All I currently have is a SID for that user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you have to call Win32 API **LogonUser** function to get windows account token back so you can then impersonate.

Comment: Hmm, that explains why I can't get it work properly... Is there any other way to get that path? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can impersonate a user without supplying password by calling ZwCreateToken.
See the CreatePureUserToken function in this article:
[GUI-Based RunAsEx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/RunUser.aspx)
You must be running as an admin (or LocalSystem) for this to work.

Another technique is to use Windows Subauthentication Packages.
This allows you to override windows built-in authentication and allow a LogonUser to succeed even if no password was supplied. See this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216828).